# How to sort a json response based on key using in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having following json response and i want to store it in a list with sorted format.
i need to use the key sort_order from the response to sort the items. can anyone help me to do this, i tried many ways, but cant achieve that. thanks

```js
{
  "result": "success",
  "reason": "Operation completed successfully.",
  "api": "get_menus",
  "locked": false,
  "payload": [ {
    "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
    "sort_order": 2470,
    "header_text": null,
    "total_price": "1.9",
    "quan_limit": 6,
    "indigent_kit": 0,
    "product_code": "9260",
    "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
    "product_desc": "SHOWER SHOES - MED",
    "spanish_desc": "chanclas de ducha- mediano"
  }, {
    "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
    "sort_order": 480,
    "header_text": null,
    "total_price": "1.9",
    "quan_limit": 6,
    "indigent_kit": 0,
    "product_code": "9265",
    "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
    "product_desc": "SHOWER SHOES - LG",
    "spanish_desc": "chanclas de ducha- grande"
  }, {
    "macs_menu_id": "1047-2000000366",
    "sort_order": 1490,
    "header_text": null,
    "total_price": "1.9",
    "quan_limit": 6,
    "indigent_kit": 0,
    "product_code": "9267",
    "menu_prod_cat": "CLTH",
    "product_desc": "SHOWER SHOE - XL",
    "spanish_desc": "chanclas de ducha- XL"
  }
```

and my kotlin code is

```
val tmpProductDetailsForSave = ArrayList<ResponseMenuDetail.Payload>()
    val fromResponseProductDetails =
        response.body()!!.payload as ArrayList<ResponseMenuDetail.Payload>
    for (s in fromResponseProductDetails) {
        if (s.product_code != null && s.macs_menu_id == macMenuId) {
            tmpProductDetailsForSave.add(s)
        }
    }
    tmpProductDetailsForSave.sortWith(Comparator { a, b ->
        val valA: String = a.sort_order
        val valB: String = b.sort_order
        valA.compareTo(valB)
    })
    basketItemList.addAll(tmpProductDetailsForSave)
```

Comment: Did you try `val sorted = tmpProductDetailsForSave.sortBy { it.sort_order}` ?

Comment: nope not tried this. but somehow i tried one option like that. but i got error in "it" key. i will try this one and let yoy know